# jquery fullcalendar click callback after loading

Tags: php, jquery, click, fullcalendar

I'm working with php, jquery and fullcalendar ( http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ )

I've setted a function on click event

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function(event) {
   myFunct(event);
  }
);
```

Now, when I load this page, I have 2 cases:
- 1) with NULL $_GET[idEvent] and this simply work
- 2) with $_GET[idEvent] In this case, I want that automatically start the callback associated on click event of my fullcalendar

I decided to slightly modify fullcalendar source and add a "id" attr on each rendered event, and then write this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#idEvt'.$id.'").click();
          </script>';
}
```

I do not think theoretically that the code is wrong..but it not work...probably because the loading of the calendar takes a long time to load and my ** $("#idEvt'.$id.'")** is not found.

Can anyone  help me or has already used fullcalendar?

---

EDIT:

Thank you! This is the solution:

I've add a jquery function to bring get variables from url

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});
```

Then in fullcalendar initialization

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function(event) {
    myFunct(event);
  },
  eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view ) { 
    var idEvt = $.getUrlVar('id');
    if(event.id==idEvt){
        myFunct(event);
    }
}
```

In this way is not necessary modify fullcalendar source code or use php.
Thank you for suggestion!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for **eventAfterRender** callback. This will be called immediately after event is placed at its final position on the calendar. You can check for certain values and then decide whether or not to call a function. [Click Here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/) to see the parameters accepted by this callback.